# How can I stop the Find and Replace window from vanishing?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have positioned the *Find in Files* and the *Find Results 1* windows just where I want them.
But when I click the *Find All* button the *Find and Replace* window vanishes and I have to manually bring it back from the Edit menu.

Why is this and how can I stop it !

(I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition)

Comment: The only way I found to keep it from disappearing is to dock it into one of the main window tabs.

Comment: Thanks @CrnaStena that does seem to be the only way! Not what I wanted though.  Hoping someone will have a workaround ... ?

Answer (score 0):

After pressing the *Find All* button and going through your results you can just click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to make it visible again. Avoid closing of the *Find Results* window, it will disappear automatically.